# Is there some CSS parameter I can apply to a table to make it so the user cannot click it?

Tags: html, css

I have a normal CSS table:

```
            <table class="form grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>EId</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            ...
```

The table contains labels and some input fields. When data is being retrieved with an Ajax call I would like to make it so the user cannot click on the table. Ideally I would like to make the table appear a bit less dark for the black on white background theme and a bit darker for the white on black background theme. Is there some way I can do this with CSS?

Comment: [Yes for modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: it sounds like a job for JS, not CSS. `$('table').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: I am looking for a modern browser solution. IE10 and above

Comment: To your second question (which should ideally have been a different question), can you use `opacity`? (This would depend on the other CSS now in use; you say you're using a theme, so there's probably already a lot of it.)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do that with  `pointer-events`

```
table{
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

`Pointer-events` is supported on most major browsers: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events, however if you want compatibility with older IE, it could be easier to create a div with a transparent png background and overlay it on top of the table.

Alternatively, you can use JS `e.preventDefault();` as pointed out by yoavmatchulsky.

Comment: This is interesting. I never heard about this CSS style before.

Comment: Good point @Mr_Green, if you need IE10 support @Samantha J, you can use this [polyfill](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill) approach. Simply add the js script to your `<head>` tag and `pointer-events` will work flawlessly. https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill

Answer (score 2):

You could add a class `disabled` to table with the following styles :

```
table.disabled > * {
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.40;
  -moz-opacity: 0.40;

}
```

for a markup like this :

```
<table class="form grid disabled">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>EId</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
...
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/f9Fwq/